# Define constant in main app module and use it in another constant in same module

Tags: angularjs, environment-variables, constants

i'm trying to create some type of release/development environment in AngularJS so that i can easily deploy releases without havinv to go through multiple files changing some settings..

Problem is i'm getting a undefined variable after i explcitly declare a constant on my app.js to know the type of environment i'm actually using.

Console log has no errors/logs.

**App.js**

```
angular.module('App', ['ionic', 'app.controllers', 'app.services', 'ngCordova'])
  .constant('ENVIRONMENT', 'DEV')
  .constant('baseServiceUrl', (function() {
    alert(this.ENVIRONMENT); //outputs: undefined
    return (this.ENVIRONMENT == 'DEV') ? 'api-dev.azureexample.com/' : 'api-release.azureexample.com/';
  }) ())
  .constant('apiAcessKey', (function() {
    return (this.ENVIRONMENT == 'DEV') ? '?key=somekeyfordev' : '?key=somekeyforrelease';
  }) ())
  .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    /** some more code **/
```

So, any ideias ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant define a constant from a constant, but you can use a service to do the trick... see [working plunker.](https://plnkr.co/edit/sq2yl2qGNgytx3xY80ZL?p=preview)

Here is the code:

```
angular.module('plunker', [])
 .constant('ENVIRONMENT', 'DEV')
  .service('urls',function(ENVIRONMENT){ this.apiUrl = (ENVIRONMENT == 'DEV') ? 'api-dev.azureexample.com/' : 'api-release.azureexample.com/';
  })
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, urls) {
  $scope.name = urls.apiUrl;
});
```

My app just display the URL:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

Why cant you define a constant from a constant? If you want to create a constant A that depends on constant B, you would need to tell angular that A depends on B using dependency injection. But constant do not have dependency, this is why I use a service instead that allows to define a dependency.

Answer (score 2):

`constant` and `value` services are supposed to hold constants and can't be injected with dependencies. IIFE here

```
  .constant('baseServiceUrl', (function() {
    alert(this.ENVIRONMENT); //outputs: undefined
    return (this.ENVIRONMENT == 'DEV') ? 'api-dev.azureexample.com/' : 'api-release.azureexample.com/';
  }) ())
```

doesn't make use of DI and won't have `this.ENVIRONMENT`, unless it was defined on `this` (which is `window`).

`constant`s that make use of other `constant`s s should be defined in `config`:

```
app.config(($provide, ENVIRONMENT) => {
  $provide.constant('baseServiceUrl', ENVIRONMENT == 'DEV'
    ? 'api-dev.azureexample.com/'
    : 'api-release.azureexample.com/'
  );
})
```

Since `baseServiceUrl` and `apiAcessKey` are obviously expected to be used during run phase, it is appropriate to define them as `factory` services instead:

```
app.factory('baseServiceUrl', (ENVIRONMENT) => {
  return ENVIRONMENT == 'DEV'
    ? 'api-dev.azureexample.com/'
    : 'api-release.azureexample.com/';
})
```